# Preprocessing Data for training CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning field. I have started learning to train different datasets (like Fashion_mnist, CIFAR10, etc.) using different NN or CNN models. I have difficulty understanding the data-preprocessing steps. For example, after loading the dataset and splitting into training and test data, sometimes the dataset is further processed using ImageDataProcessor and sometimes directly used in model.fit. The labelled data is sometimes processed with OneHotEncoder and sometimes with to_categorical. Is there a template that one can refer to for training a specific type of dataset with some specific CNN Model, or is there some book (chapter) or references that a beginner can refer repeatedly to gain understanding and practice more.

I thank all the experts who can guide me here :)

Comment: Hi, every dataset is different so as it is every architecture. You just have to experiment with different tools and configurations. After a while you will gain enough experience to know what's best for your dataset and model. There is no magic formula that can work for all problems, actually this is what makes training and working with NNs difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this question is what every new-joiner to "Machine learning World" may ask :)

---

Every dataset is built with a specific goal. i.e Some are for Semantic Segmentation , some other are for object detection and etc. so, for each of them, you may have to do some new preprocessing steps to get your data ready!

---

let's make an example. consider you are trying to build a simple decision tree for task of "Image classification". let's make it simple. we want our model to predict if our image is a cat or not. we may have many different features as input. one of them maybe of "categorical" kind. for example earShape of animals is "Pointy" or "fluffy" or "oval" :) Now, to make our decision tree simple and efficient, we use "One Hot Encoding" to convert our "categorical data" into "numerical data". as so, we now have 3 new columns indicating if an animal has "Pointy" ears (1 or 0), "fluffy" ears (1 or 0), "oval" ears (1 or 0).
Now, our decision tree can make predictions better! if we consider spliting root node on "is Pointy or not" it has 2 edges (1 or 0). so, we somewhat expanded our initial dataset and removed "earShape" feature and replaced it with 3 new features with One Hot Encoding.

---

As you see, in machine learning, we have different approaches for dealing with data! actually, someone may say that "how to treat data" is a specialization called "Data Engineering" and needs experience working on different datasets and knowing the needs of our machine learning model!
(The example of Decision Tree was just to explain the process! We have this process also in NNs and CNNs and etc.)

---

If there are any questions, please don't hesitate to ask :)